# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Incorrect login details were provided

Tags: javascript, node.js, бот

[image: Ошибка]

Исправил ошибки в коде для бота, и как видно в верху изображения добавил одну команду для него, но при попытке запустить появляется эта ошибка 
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Incorrect login details were provided. И вопрос: что это за ошибка и о каких неверных данных идет речь?

Comment: Для промисов нужно всегда `catch` блок писать.

Comment: И да, код и стектрейс тут принято вставлять текстом (:

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let config = require('./botconfig.json');
let token = config.token;
let prefix = config.prefix;
```

В этом фрагменте я подключал токен из другого файла который называется `botconfig.json`
где у меня записан как раз таки токен бота и префикс по которому он будет определять команду ... 
И так в чем заключалась проблема, она заключалась в том что на сайте дискорда во вкладке разработчика я случайно изменил токен бота по которому бот запускался, а в самом коде это сделать забыл... И когда изменил токен в редакторе на верный который указан на страничке разработчика бот запустился